# Where is the short description magento html page?

Tags: magento

All quick question I've gone to

```
app/design/frontend/default/<theme>/catalog/product/
```

Im trying to find the page where the short description comes from I just want to change the title of the short description. Ive turned on template paths but that doesn't help, any ideas where I could find the page ?

Comment: This is usually found in the controller

Comment: can you be a bit more descriptive I've gone to app/code/mage/catalog/controllers and not seeing anything helpful :(

Comment: I don't have Magento, but I think it must be somewhere modules -> default -> controllers -> CatalogController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template you are looking for is `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`.
In the default theme the code that renders the description looks like this:

```
        <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
            <div class="short-description">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
```